# Starting emacs with eshell and file from command line argument

Tags: init-file, buffers, eshell

I am trying to start emacs with both eshell and the specified file, but displaying the buffer with the file.

When I add the following line to emacs

```
(add-hook 'emacs-startup-hook (lambda () (eshell)))
```

then eshell also loads on startup with the file, but eshell is shown instead of the file.

I tried to change the `initial-buffer-choice` variable so that the file is shown instead, but am not sure what function to give to return the file specified in command line.
Can anyone please give me some ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `emacs-startup-hook` is (docstring, obtained with `C-h v emacs-startup-hook`)

> run after loading init files and handling the command line.

The command `previous-buffer` should do what you want.

> In selected window switch to previous buffer.

```el
(add-hook 'emacs-startup-hook (lambda () (eshell) (previous-buffer)))
```